Java 8 to Java 17 update issue
I updated my project to Java 17 and latest Spring Boot version. While hitting any API getting below error.
2024-04-10 16:42:05.116 IST -APP-   [http-nio-9092-exec-1] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet].log-175 - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Filter execution threw an exception] with root cause 
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class com.xxxx.authorization.filter.CachingRequestBodyFilter does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void doFilterInternal(jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse, jakarta.servlet.FilterChain)' of abstract class org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)
2024-04-10 16:42:05.135 IST -APP-   [http-nio-9092-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.traceDebug-120 - "ERROR" dispatch for POST "/error", parameters={} 
2024-04-10 16:42:05.142 IST -APP-   [http-nio-9092-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.getHandler-531 - Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest) 


Are you using dependency management from Spring Boot? It seems to me you are having mismatching libraries.

Also, you have to use the jakarta namespace. Are you using @Override annotations? It should have told you you are not overriding the method.

What is your spring boot version? Please share some code or a even better, a minimal reproducible example. Right now I can only guess what your problem is.

This sounds more like a Spring Boot update issues than a Java 8 to Java 17 update issue.

Check your imports in com.xxxx.authorization.filter.CachingRequestBodyFilter, and update javax.* imports to jakarta.* .
More info can be found here:

The entire Spring team, and many in our community of contributors, are now preparing for the next generation of Spring. We are planning to release Spring Boot 3.0 in November 2022. This next major revision will be based on Spring Framework 6.0 and will require Java 17 or above. It will also be the first version of Spring Boot that makes use of Jakarta EE 9 APIs (jakarta.) instead of EE 8 (javax.).


If we have other library like this having dependeincies of javax.* packages, do we need to update all or is there be any other solution as well ?

Correct. Update your project's dependencies to their latest version and read their changelogs for the implications.
